# PSSetSamplers doens't work (The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler)

Tags: shader, directx-11, hlsl, c++-cx, pixel-shader

I'm very new at directx11, and I wanted to add texture to a shader I'm using.
(until now, I hadn't used any texture yet in directx11)

But sampling doesn't seem to work (it's always float4(0,0,0,0)), and I get the warning: "D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler to be set at Slot 0, but none is bound."

I searched for this, but all answers say to use

```
_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &_sampler);
```

But I already do that.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

This is my entire shader:

```
Texture2D tex;
SamplerState TexSampler : register(S0)
{
    Texture = (Slope);
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
};

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 color : COLOR0;
    //.r : slope
    //.g : relative distance on road (compared the the rider)
    //.b : shadow (currently darker on lower parts)
    //.a : cameradepth
    float fogfactor : COLOR1;
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    const float4 fogColor = float4(0.9, 0.9, 1, 1);

    const float halfWidth = 0.0016f;

    float4 color;

    if (input.color.g < -halfWidth * input.color.a)
    {
        color = float4(0.5, 0.85, 1, 1);
    }
    else if (input.color.g < halfWidth * input.color.a)
    {
        color = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        color = tex.Sample(TexSampler, float2(input.color.r, 0.5));
    }

    if (input.color.b < 0.999)
    {
        input.color.b *= 0.94; //makes the sides a bit darker
    }
    color.rgb *= input.color.b;

    color.rgb = lerp(color.rgb, fogColor.rgb, input.fogfactor);

    return color;
}
```

And in c++/cx I do this (not the full code, just fragments):

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView>    _slopeGradient;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11SamplerState>          _sampler;

D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
ZeroMemory(&sampDesc, sizeof(sampDesc));
sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
sampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
sampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
_d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, &_sampler);

_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &_slopeGradient);
_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &_sampler);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your usage of [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr). The `operator&` overload for `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` calls `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf`, not `GetAddressOf`. Therefore, you are basically doing this right now which is always setting these resources to `nullptr` (i.e. clearing the slot):

```
_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, _slopeGradient.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());
_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, _sampler.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());
```

You should use:

```
_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, _slopeGradient.GetAddressOf());
_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, _sampler.GetAddressOf());
```

> The old ATL `CComPtr` had the `operator&` overload map to`GetAddressOf` but asserted that it was a nullptr which often resulted in inadvertent memory leaks. The `operator&` is assumed to be used in initialization by these smart-pointers, and that's not what you are doing here. You really want the address of the initialized raw pointer.

Remember that both of these methods are actually taking an array of COM pointers. In C you can of course treat a pointer as an array of size one, but you may find it more clear to do something like:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srvs[] = { _slopeGradient.GetAddressOf() };
_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, _countof(srvs), srvs);

ID3D11SamplerState* samplers[] = { _sampler.GetAddressOf() };
_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, _countof(samplers), samplers);
```

Also note that you are defining some elements of the legacy [Effects system](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki) in your HLSL source that is ignored in standard DirectX API usage. You can just delete it.

```
{
    Texture = (Slope);
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
}
```

> As you are new to DirectX 11, you should look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about that. I changed it and now the warning is gone, but I get the same visual result. Any idea? I must admit that I am new to c++/cx as well as directx11 unfortunately. I actually started using DirectXTK, but it seems to work a bit differently than the things I already had, and I am trying to combine it, but I don't seem to get it working.

Comment: Graphics debugging is challenging as there are numerous ways for it to go wrong and end up with a blank screen. Note that DirectX 11 is a COM API, so it doesn't matter if you are using C++/CX or pure C++ for it as it's the same on all the Direct3D platforms. You may want to work through the DirectX Tool Kit tutorials independently of your current project and then go back to it once you have a handle on things.

Comment: I think that is indeed the best thing to do. Thanks for the help.